# App crashed when cropping is saved and crop size is equal or greater than initial size using code by markuspalme

Tags: android, image, android-intent, xamarin.android, crop

First, I want to credit the owner for his simplified work of flexible cropping.
https://github.com/markuspalme/cropimage-xamarin.
Original project found here
https://github.com/MMP-forTour/cropimage

My goal is to crop a photo so I can choose where and what part I really want to have. I tried using the method of intent. **`Intent cropIntent = new Intent ("com.android.camera.action.CROP");`**. But since it is not for all device, I have to look for other solution.

The algorithm from https://github.com/markuspalme/cropimage-xamarin is perfectly working when the crop size is smaller than the initial size. See image below (this is from their site).

[image: Crop sample with initial size]

The problem is, when crop size is equal or greater than the initial size it crashes the app. My guess is that it is too much for bundle extras to hold.

Here is the code where it is crashing.

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.PutParcelable("data", croppedImage);
SetResult(Result.Ok,
    (new Intent()).SetAction("inline-data").PutExtras(extras));
Finish();
```

Here is the snippet of crashing croppedImage data.
[image: Crashing Image Data]

Here is the snippet of prefectly working croppedImage data.
[image]

I don't know what is something that Bundle Extras can't handle. Please help me with this. Thanks